# Do case statements have to be used for links in PHP?

Tags: php, menu, switch-statement, interpreter, event-driven

I've been given a school project which involves creating an online invoicing system in PHP.
My teacher seems to be convinced that the only way to have a menu (with fixed pages like "display", etc) is to use case statements.
My first guess would have been to just use a function which echo's some hrefs.

He also keeps saying that PHP is event driven. Is this true? I was always thought the interpreter on the server went through the code and then sent the html to the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect he means using `case` for handling the menu items when selected, not for rendering them to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP isn't event driven at all.  Altho it exists [Photon](http://www.photon-project.com/) that is a framework to achive that.
And there are multiple ways to have menu. If with `case` you mean `switch ... case`: the answer is no. It is not the only way.

The way I make menu is with an array

```
$menu = array(
   'url 1'=>'Element 1 ',
   'url 2'=>'Element 2 ',
   'url 3'=>'Element 3 ' 
);
```

With this array knowing which is the element selected is pretty simple with no need of a case statement

Comment: That's what I thought. I did mean case. What would you do for the menu structure?

Comment: @Edward: updated... Alto I didn't consider for hierarchical items. But it's not that hard to innest array from there